# How do I find df for a Hausman test?

Tags: statistical-significance, econometrics

I am given a result of 17.2 for a Hausman test, and told to interpret it. I am trying to figure out the p-value, but I don't understand what my df is supposed to be. The null is that the coefficients are the same between FE and RE model. PLS help!

Answer (score 0):

The df for the Hausman test:
$$H = (b_1 - b_0)'(var(b_0) - var(b_1))^t(b_1 - b_0)$$

where  the two b's are vectors of coefficients for the two regressions and the $^t$ is the Moore Penrose inverse is the rank of the matrix $var(b_0) - var(b_1)$

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Wu%E2%80%93Hausman_test) for the derivation and more details.